# Building Gradle EARs from pre-built WARs

Tags: gradle, build.gradle

I'm using Gradle and want to build an EAR that includes a pre-built WAR file found in a repository.  I got things working like this:

```
dependencies
{
    earlib 'PathName:NameOfPreBuiltWar:Version@war'
}

ear 
{
    libDirName '/'
}
```

This seems to work perfectly, but isn't the way earlib or libDirName were intended to be used.  Is there a better way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ear plugin also provides a `deploy` configuration, so this should be sufficient:

```
dependencies {
    deploy 'PathName:NameOfPreBuiltWar:Version@war'
}
```